# How to run Plasma Discover on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (not Kubuntu)?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, kde, mate, lxde

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE installed.

The system is fully upgraded, does not have PPAs and/or thirdparty repositories added.

I have installed Plasma Discover by the following simple commands:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-discover \
plasma-discover-flatpak-backend plasma-discover-snap-backend
```

When I try to launch it from GUI - it does not open.

If I try to open it from terminal I get:

```
$ plasma-discover 
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/DiscoverWindow.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

Errors when loading the GUI
no packages for "org.gnome.DiskUtility"
no packages for "org.mate-desktop.mate-eiciel"
no packages for "org.gnome.DejaDup"
empty appstream db
setting currentApplicationBackend PackageKitBackend(0x557c7d4a1c00)
```

What should I do to fix these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported [bug 1788863](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-discover/+bug/1788863) about missed dependencies.

Afterwards I visited [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/qml-module-qtquick-controls/filelist) and found necessary dependency - package `qml-module-qtquick-controls`.

Installation of it with

```
sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls
```

But this is not enough, here is other error message:

> qrc:/qml/ReviewDialog.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed

so we need to install other package

```
sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
```

fixes the problem - Plasma Discover starts and works normally:

[image: Plasma Discovery on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

During its operation it was discovered that it needs `kded_kcookiejar` from  `kdelibs5-plugins` package.

So the complete command to use Plasma Discover is:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-discover \
plasma-discover-flatpak-backend plasma-discover-snap-backend \
qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs kdelibs5-plugins
```

---

Note: this method is actual for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell too.

Comment: Someone else had a similar experience. One of the KDE devs [had written this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392737#c1): "Yes, Discover should definitely work in other desktop environments. However, what you describe is a packaging issue in Debian; packages that are required aren't getting installed by default, boo! This is probably masked by the fact that the missing packages are always installed for other reasons in a KDE Plasma environment, so nobody noticed that the Discover packaging wasn't marking them as dependencies correctly."

Comment: Thank you for the link. I discovered, that `...dialogs` is also needed. Just tested on GNOME, we need to install two dependencies manually.

Comment: By the way, Lubuntu Cosmic has Discover installed by default so I couldn't check for missing dependencies :)

Comment: Hey, when are you going to drop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime?  **:-)**