# How can I have latest Dolphin file manager on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, dolphin

I can find it in the software center but its version is pretty old(still 2016). How can I get the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04.
Also want to know is there any possibility to apply gtk theme on dolphin?

Comment: What do you see with `apt policy dolphin`? Keep in mind installing `dolphin` will pull in a lot of dependencies. Also, qt-based apps may not look "native" in GNOME-based systems as you seem to know.

Comment: @DKBose   Candidate: 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1   Version table:4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1

Comment: That is the version I have in Kubuntu 18.04. So that's what you'll get now.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, though latest version is 18.08.0

Comment: Yes, but then you'll need to switch to Arch Linux or Manjaro or other rolling releases or KDE Neon Bionic when that's ready ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer Dolphin may be obtained from [KDE FlatPak repository](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Flatpak):

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists kdeapps --from https://distribute.kde.org/kdeapps.flatpakrepo
flatpak install kdeapps org.kde.dolphin
```

The command above will download `org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11` (about 332 Mb), `org.kde.dolphin/x86_64/master` and `org.kde.dolphin.Locale/x86_64/master`. Logout from your account and login back. Then search in dash for Dolphin and launch it:

[image: Dolphin 18.11.70 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS GNOME]

(you got Dolphin 18.11.70 running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

Theoretically speaking you can get all KDE applications as FlatPak with help of [KDE Plasma Discover](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068567/66509) or with `flatpak install kdeapps org.kde.` <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.